# But why? Chrome javascript function strange result

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

```
function foo() { return typeof null === 'undefined'; }
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) console.log(foo());
```

Run code in Chrome console and see results:

```
132 false
868 true
```

But why?

Comment: What are the numbers for? In my mind, null should never equal undefined, as null is a value in itself, but undefined is just showing a variable as unassigned

Comment: `(132)` and `(868)` (when inside small "bubbles") refer to the number of times each line has been repeated. In your case, `false` has been printed the first 132 cases, and `true` in the last 868 cases.

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a bug in Chrome's Javascript engine. `typeof null === "object"` is [the expected behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null), and `typeof null === "undefined"` should never be `true`.

Comment: This is really interesting question. I do not know why but I would expect the output to be 1000's of true or false but not both. I'm curious whether Google Chrome developers would contribute in your thread.

Comment: This is a bug in the Chrome V8 JIT compiler, and only exists in Chrome 50: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604033

Comment: @KyleFalconer: Not sure whether you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @KyleFalconer not only V50, I'm test at chrome 51.0.2704.103m (64 bit) and code worked exactly as shown.

Comment: Firefox 44.0.2:

[screenshot](https://habrastorage.org/files/a49/abc/0dd/a49abc0dd92d4bc49a7dd5f66aab55e4.png)